# Incorrect path to recsource file using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, workspace, getresource

I'm using a file from resources dir, calling it using the code: 
`XmlDataLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("testData").getPath()`

It works well on my local machine and the path to the file is correct: 
`C:/Work/PROJECT_NAME/test/selenium/target/classes/testData`

Then I would like it to be used in Jenkins job on the server in linux environment but I get the NullPointerException:

`[WARNING] File 'var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/test/selenium/target/classes/testData/' does not exist`

It is because there is a lost "workspace" directory between "project" and "test" folders in the path. The correct path should be: 
`var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/ws/test/selenium/target/classes/testData`
Required file is really exists there, but for some reason Jenkins build 
incorrect path, loosing the `/ws/` directory. 
Can anyone give me a hand please? Why does `class.getClassLoader().getResource("testData").getPath()` doesnt work properly on the server?

I have resources set in Maven pom file:

`<resource>
   <directory>resources</directory>
 </resource>`

Comment: is the ws there becouse it is a multiaxis project?

Comment: Not sure I'm with you, what does it mean - 'multiaxis project'? `ws` folder - it is project's Workspace, where all the files and folders are. As I can see, each project in Jenkind has it's own ws folder

Comment: what happens when you use the following `this.getClass().getResource("testData").getPath();`

Answer (score 0):

Using `.getResource("testData")` can cause issues as you never know if the resource is even accessible.

[At runtime, the resource folder is seldom in the same location on disk as it is in our source code.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classpath-resource-cannot-be-opened) So we need another way of accessing the files.

Therefore the preferred way is to use `getResourceAsStream(String)` which returns an InputStream you can directly read from.

Best to load resources from the classpath instead of a specific file location:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testData");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
String contents = reader.lines()
  .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```